# Limited Connection issue on Android Emulator

Tags: windows, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to connect to wifi in android emulator but wifi is getting connected with limited connection. Becasue of which i am not able to access internet in emulator. Device used is Galaxy Nexus, API level: 30, Android :11.0.

Nothing seems to be working. Has anybody faced this issue and found a solution?

Any help would be of great help:

[image]
[image]

I have tried solutions available for No Internet issue but nothing worked for me